# Resorting array by lowest to highest

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array which needs to be re ordered "TH Thickness" lowest to highest. Not sure how I could accomplish this.

Any ideas?

```
[thickness] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [TH Thickness ID] => 23
                [TH Thickness] => 100
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [TH Thickness ID] => 24
                [TH Thickness] => 120
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [TH Thickness ID] => 33
                [TH Thickness] => 150
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [TH Thickness ID] => 25
                [TH Thickness] => 50
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [TH Thickness ID] => 21
                [TH Thickness] => 60
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [TH Thickness ID] => 26
                [TH Thickness] => 70
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [TH Thickness ID] => 22
                [TH Thickness] => 80
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP >= 5.5.0**

```
array_multisort(array_column($array['thickness'], 'TH Thickness'), SORT_ASC, $array['thickness']);
```

**PHP < 5.5.0** - You can look at the possible duplicates for your question, or:

```
foreach($array['thickness'] as $k => $v) {
   $sort[$k] = $v['TH Thickness'];
}
array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $array['thickness']);
```

Comment: Are there any alternatives? The server I'm working with uses 5.4

Comment: @BenShepherd: look at the duplicates or my edit.

Comment: Had to fiddle around a tad but finally got it working. Cheers!